# How can I add yes/no dialog to jquery mobile page?

Tags: jquery-mobile, live, jquery-ui-dialog, alert

When I added `$(document).ready({alert('it is ready')});` into script tags on the SiteMaster.master page and called the page with this link: `http://192.168.1.66:90/Reminder/test.aspx#DialogChangeTag.aspx` I doesn't work until I called it with `http://192.168.1.66:90/Reminder/DialogChangeTag.aspx` link.

Where am I making mistake?
DialogChangeTag.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/TekContent.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeFile="DialogChangeTag.aspx.cs" Inherits="DialogChangeTag" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="PageIdContent" runat="Server">
    <div data-role="page" id="delete_dialog" data-theme="b">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                alert("calis");
            }); 
        </script>
        <div data-role="content" data-theme="b">
            <h1>
                Delete Item?</h1>
            <p>
                Are you sure you want to delete this item?</p>
            <a href="#" class="delete-dialog-yes" data-role="button" data-theme="b">Yes</a>
            <a href="#" class="delete-dialog-no" data-role="button" data-theme="b">No</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Test.aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/TekContent.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeFile="test.aspx.cs" Inherits="test" %>

<asp:Content ID="ContentPage" ContentPlaceHolderID="PageIdContent" runat="Server">
    <div data-role="page" id="pageTest">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="inline">
            <h1>
                TEST HEADER</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <h2>
                TEST CONTENT</h2>
            <a href="DialogChangeTag.aspx" data-role="button" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="pop">
                Show Dialog</a>
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer" class="ui-bar" id="divFooterContainer">
            <h3>
                TEST FOOTER</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably because your jQuery Mobile is setup to work with AJAX. `$(document).load()` only gets called when a new page is loaded in the browser. This means `$(document).load()` won't work when you are working with AJAX based pages. Unwraping `$(document).load()` would solve it if that page is only loaded with AJAX. A better way of solving this problem is using unobtrusive client side code. Take a look at Backbone.js.